# Why isn't the forecolor of header and rows of gridview not changing?

Tags: css, asp.net

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        Width="847px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" onrowdeleting="Gridview1_rowDeleted" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="orange" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="orange" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000000" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

The result of this gridview is that the header fonts are displayed in orange although I changed them to black. Also, the font color of both rows and headers of all the gridviews were orange from the point I added the gridviews. Why can't I change the color to my wish?

The css part is:-

```
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,nav ul,nav li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border-style: none;
border-color: inherit;
border-width: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size:small;
vertical-align:baseline;
color: #FF9933;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `table,th,tr,thead,tbody,td` from your css part.

Answer (score 0):

you can write css class and set the cssClass Property